# .NET 5 - Cookie authetication on challenge rewrite/re-execute instead of redirect

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication

We're currently migrating a .NET Framework 4.8 MVC app to .NET (Core) 5 and I'm encountering a challenge.

In the old Framework app, we implement `AuthorizeAttribute` where an override on `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` will clear the content of the response and 're'-execute another controller (with the help of `IControllerFactory`). This essentially creates a login landing page where the URL stays the same (same request). For each secured page with this attribute, we have a different page that we render (a 'sales pitch' as you will).

Now in .NET Core, authentication works differently than in .NET Framework. So I believe the approach described earlier will not work here. I think the correct approach is to configure cookie authentication to handle this. But we have two business requirements that make this a little challenging:

1. No redirections; instead, show the login page on the first request, so basically, URL rewrite/re-execute instead of redirect
2. Each page requiring authentication should render a different login page

My challenge lies in the first requirement. I need to find a way to render a different controller action on authentication. A URL re-execute will be fine, too, as we already do this in a custom UseStatusCodePages handler. The `AddAuthentication().AddCookie(o => o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context => { ... }` looks like the place where I could handle my logic, but nothing I tried works. A reason might be that this is too far into the middleware?

So the question is: how to do a rewrite or re-execute instead of a redirect on the authentication challenge?

Comment: I'm afraid not.It is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a colleague and looking at the source code of the `UseStatusCodePages` and `UseRewriter` features we have come up with a solution to the problem.

We ended up with implementing the `OnRedirectToLogin` event on the `AddCookie`. When this event gets triggered we find the URI of the current login page that we need to show. But instead of setting the `context.RedirectUri` we instead add it to the `context.HttpContext.Items` dictionary. We then use custom middleware to look for that item and do the rewrite/re-execute there. The `return Task.CompletedTask;` makes sure nothing happens, no redirect. Without the middleware, we get a blank page.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(o =>
{
    o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        var loginPageUri = GetLoginLandingPageUri(context);

        context.HttpContext.Items[ReExecuteUriMiddleware.ReExecuteUriItemKey] = loginPageUri;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

When the middleware sees that item in the Items dictionary we reset the endpoint information, so when we call the `_next` for the second time, the middleware pipeline will nicely re-execute the request, but with a different path.

```
public class ReExecuteUriMiddleware
{
    public const string ReExecuteUriItemKey = "ReExecuteUri";
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ReExecuteUriMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);

        if (httpContext.Items[ReExecuteUriItemKey] is string reExecuteUri)
        {
            // An endpoint may have already been set. Since we're going to re-invoke the middleware pipeline we need to reset
            // the endpoint and route values to ensure things are re-calculated.
            httpContext.SetEndpoint(null);
            var routeValuesFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>();
            routeValuesFeature?.RouteValues?.Clear();

            httpContext.Request.Path = reExecuteUri;

            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And ofcourse we added it in the `Startup` class right after the `app.UseStatusCodePages()`.

```
app.UseMiddleware<ReExecuteUriMiddleware>();
```